# How to use Jackson with runtime generics?

Tags: java, json, generics, jackson, deserialization

I'm new to Jackson and have problem to deserialize JSON with generic field. This is a JSON I want to parse using Jackson.

```
{
  "topic": {
    "headline": {
      ...
    },
    "body": [
      {
        "type": "complex",
        "content": {
          "player_template": "12345",
          "width": 600,
          "height": 338,
          "url": "http://...",
          "caption": "foobar",
          "vid": "12345",
          "watch_url": "http://...",
          "embed_html": "<script..."
        },
        "preview_image_url": "https://...",
        "position": 0
      },
      {
        "content": "foobar",
        "type": "simple",
        "position": 1
      }
    ],
    "type": "some type",
    "part": "image",
    "box_link": [
      {
        ...
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

**Note**

`topic > body > element[0] > content` is a `object`, but `topic > body > element[1] > content` is a `string`. The `body` elements may contain only `string`s or `object`s or both.

Here are Java classes for `body` and `content`.

```
public class Body<T> {

    // @JsonDeserialize(using = ContentDeserializer.class)
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
    @JsonSubTypes({
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = String.class, name = "simple"),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Content.class, name = "complex")
    })
    @JsonProperty("content")
    private T mContent;

    @JsonProperty("type")
    private String mType;

    @JsonProperty("preview_image_url")
    private String mPreviewImageUrl;

    @JsonProperty("position")
    private int mPosition;

    // getter and setter
}

public class Content {

    @JsonProperty("player_template")
    private String mPlayerTemplate;

    @JsonProperty("width")
    private int mWidth;

    @JsonProperty("height")
    private int mHeight;

    @JsonProperty("url")
    private String mUrl;

    @JsonProperty("caption")
    private String mCaption;

    @JsonProperty("vid")
    private String mVid;

    @JsonProperty("watch_url")
    private String mWatchUrl;

    @JsonProperty("embed_html")
    private String mEmbedHtml;

    // getter and setter
}
```

I try to map JSON to POJO using `JsonSubTypes` annotation, so if `type` is equal to `complex` then JSON should be mapped to `Content` class, for `simple` type the mapping class should be `String` object. The problem is that Jackson convert `complex` content to `LinkedHashMap` what I don't want. For `simple` content there is no problem, it will be converted to `String`, but I think Jackson use inner logic to map this right way.

If I try to use `JsonDeserialize` annotation, then no deserializer method was called. It is like Jackson ignores annotations and make his own work.

Where I did make a mistake? What should I do to parse `complex` content to `Content` POJO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this problem by using a custom `JsonDeserializer`.

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = BodyDeserializer.class)
public class Body<T> {

    @JsonProperty("content")
    private T mContent;

    @JsonProperty("type")
    private String mType;

    @JsonProperty("preview_image_url")
    private String mPreviewImageUrl;

    @JsonProperty("position")
    private int mPosition;

    // getter and setter
}

public class BodyDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Body> {

    private static final String CAPTION = "caption";
    private static final String CONTENT = "content";
    private static final String COMPLEX = "complex";
    private static final String EMBED_HTML = "embed_html";
    private static final String HEIGHT = "height";
    private static final String PLAYER_TEMPLATE = "player_template";
    private static final String POSITION = "position";
    private static final String PREVIEW_IMAGE_URL = "preview_image_url";
    private static final String PROVIDER = "provider";
    private static final String TYPE = "type";
    private static final String URL = "url";
    private static final String VID = "vid";
    private static final String WATCH_URL = "watch_url";
    private static final String WIDTH = "width";

    public BodyDeserializer() {
        this(Body.class);
    }

    protected BodyDeserializer(Class<Body> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public Body deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        final ObjectCodec oc = parser.getCodec();
        final JsonNode node = oc.readTree(parser);

        return deserialize(node);
    }

    private Body deserialize(JsonNode node) {
        final String type = node.get(TYPE).asText();

        if (COMPLEX.equals(type)) {
            return deserializeToBodyWithContent(node, type);
        } else {
            return deserializeToBodyWithString(node, type);
        }
    }

    private Body deserializeToBodyWithString(JsonNode node, String type) {
        final int position = node.get(POSITION).asInt();

        return new Body<String>().setContent(node.get(CONTENT).asText()).setType(type).setPosition(position);
    }

    private Body deserializeToBodyWithContent(JsonNode node, String type) {
        final int position = node.get(POSITION).asInt();
        final String provider = node.get(PROVIDER).asText();
        final String previewImageUrl = node.get(PREVIEW_IMAGE_URL).asText();

        return new Body<Content>().setContent(createContent(node.get(CONTENT)))
                                  .setType(type)
                                  .setProvider(provider)
                                  .setPreviewImageUrl(previewImageUrl)
                                  .setPosition(position);
    }

    private Content createContent(JsonNode node) {
        final int width = node.get(WIDTH).asInt();
        final int height = node.get(HEIGHT).asInt();
        final String vid = node.get(VID).asText();
        final String url = node.get(URL).asText();
        final String caption = node.get(CAPTION).asText();
        final String watchUrl = node.get(WATCH_URL).asText();
        final String embedHtml = node.get(EMBED_HTML).asText();
        final String playerTemplate = node.get(PLAYER_TEMPLATE).asText();

        return new Content().setPlayerTemplate(playerTemplate)
                            .setWidth(width)
                            .setHeight(height)
                            .setUrl(url)
                            .setCaption(caption)
                            .setVid(vid)
                            .setWatchUrl(watchUrl)
                            .setEmbedHtml(embedHtml);
    }
}
```

This is not the best solution, but it works. I use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) now, it is a bit simpler.

Answer (score 2):

`@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubTypes` are meant to help with inheritance not generics. Since both `String` and `Content` implicitly extend `Object` you can define `mContent` as `Object`. Here is what your `Body` class would look like:

```
class Body {
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, property = "type")
    @JsonSubTypes({
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = String.class, name = "simple"),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Content.class, name = "complex")
    })
    @JsonProperty("content")
    private Object mContent;
```

When you specify

```
include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY
```

Jackson will look for `type` inside the `content` field in JSON. But in your case `type` is in  elements of the `body` array in JSON, on the same level as `content`. In this case you have to specify

```
include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY
```

so Jackson will look for `type` outside the `content` field in JSON.

Keep in mind than if you have a generic class like `Body<T>` you have to provide the type `T` to Jackson for deserialization (e.g. with a `TypeReference`). I don't see how that would work if you have want to have `Body<String>` and `Body<Content>` in the same collection/array. The type of the collection would have to be `List<Body>` which isn't generic anymore.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, but unfortunately it gives the same result `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: @ManosNikolaidis you are a saviour man, thank you so much, can we take it further and replace `Object` with generics ?